# Debezium connector for SQL Server Always ON

Tags: sql-server, debezium

I need some understanding with respect to Debezium connector for SQL Server always-on. I read in the documentation, the configuration that needs to be enabled on SQL server - like enabling **database.applicationIntent** to ReadOnly on PRIMARY REPLICA.

But I don't understand if I need to make any changes in the worker.properties where I mention the SOURCE  connection details. What would change for the below properties -

- database.hostname
- database.server.name

How can I ensure that debezium replicates the data even when SQL server PRIMARY and SECONDARY Nodes are swapped.
I tried making a connection to node1 (primary) and asked DBA to swap it so that it becomes secondary. However the replication didn't worked.

Can we provide comma separated values for the hostname and server.name properties for both primary and secondary nodes in SQL Server Always ON?

Has anyone tried it? Could you please provide some input on how should I approach it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Akshay , have you tried providing the applicationIntent as an option. An example of this is here. You can specify the applicationIntent as ReadOnly to read off the replica. The isolation needs to be snapshot as well. This should take care of the switching of the replicas automatically as the FQDN + applicationIntent option will resolve to the RO node or RW node as needed

```
        "database.dbname" : "testDB",
        "database.applicationIntent": "ReadOnly",
        "snapshot.isolation.mode": "snapshot",
```

https://github.com/debezium/debezium-examples/blob/main/sql-server-read-replica/register-sqlserver.json

Comment: Hi Ramachandran.A.G
I will give it a try. The usecase with Debezium was put on hold due to some reason but thank you for your suggestion. I will try it out once the work resumes. I will update this link after the results and observations. Thank you